# How to connect to the remote machine using c# and getting sqlserver instances?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, smo

How can i connect to the remote machine and getting the local instances using smo or any thing.

using smo i did it for local instances but i dont know the same for remote instances how to

do this.

(My idea is connecting to the rmote computer and call the EnumAvailableSqlServers(true))

Can u give me ideas to do this???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This article shows how to retrieve a list of PCs on the local network which are running MS SQL Server, and gets information about the instances, such as server name, instance name, version, and databases.

**Locate SQL Server instances on the local network**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/locate_sql_servers.aspx